# Is Meteor backend code always available on client-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I created test Meteor application and I found that overall code (server-side too) available to look with dev tools on a client.
Test app (In browser):

```
 (function(){ if (Meteor.isClient) {
      Template.hello.greeting = function () {
        return "Welcome to test_app.";
      };

      Template.helo.events({
        'click input' : function () {
          // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
          if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
            console.log("You pressed the button");
        }
      });
    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
      });
    }

    }).call(this);
```

Is this by design? Can server-side code stay at server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to keep server side code on the server you have to restructure your app.

Make these directories in the root directory of your application:

- /server - stores everything to run on the server only
- /client - stores everything to run on the client only
- /public/ - stores anything that should be accessible in at `http://yoursite/` (i.e images, fonts). If you place an image `a.jpg` in `/public` it will be available at `http://yoursite/a.jpg`

Once you use this structure you don't have to use the `if(Meteor.isServer) {..}` or `if(Meteor.isClient) {..}` conditions anymore as they would run in the right place.

When you put files in the root directory of your meteor application, they would run on both the client *and* the server so this is why the file is unaltered & everything in the `if(Meteor.isServer)` would only run on the server.

It is by design and quite helpful to share code between the server and client, though it would be visible to both the client & server

Comment: I'd like to add that even if you use if(Meteor.isServer){} it will still ship that server code to the client if it is NOT in the server folder.

Comment: It's a shame there's no direct option to use the folder layout option from 'meteor create' but you can use one of the examples as a skeleton 'meteor create --example' - Could also look at using something like: https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-boilerplate

Comment: In fact you aren't limited to a single instance of /server and /client at the root - you can use them at *any* point in your directory hierarchy to denote server-only and client-only components. So for instance, you can have a folder per functional block in your code, and for each block have a /server and a /client folder to contain the files that implement that function across server and client.  The meteor documentation implies this though it doesn't state it explicitly - but it definitely works in this work.